# Tensorflow.JS fit function stucks my program

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I would like to create my own image classifier for requirements of my project, I must not to use Python or tfjs-node, this is why I'm using tfjs.

So, I built an architecture with this function:

```
function buildModel(){

    const model = tf.sequential();
    
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        inputShape: [IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,IMAGE_CHANNELS], // 224*224*4 (3 if no alpha)
        kernelSize: 5,
        filters: 8,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling',
        
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2,2],
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        filters: 64,
        kernelSize: 5,
        activation: 'relu'
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2,2],
        padding: 'valid',
        dataFormat: null
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        filters: 32,
        kernelSize: 4,
        activation: 'relu'
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2,2],
        padding: 'valid',
        dataFormat: null
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        filters: 16,
        kernelSize: 4,
        activation: 'relu'
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({
        poolSize: [2, 2],
        strides: [2,2],
        padding: 'valid',
        dataFormat: null
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.flatten({
        dataFormat: null
    }));
    
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        units: 64,
        activation: 'relu'
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
        units: 2,
        activation: 'softmax'
    }));

    model.compile({
        optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
        loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
        metrics: ['accuracy']
    });
    return model;
}
```

This function doesn't seems to cause any trouble, but when I want to train this model, my program stucks, there is my training function:

```
async function fitModel(model){
    const tensorList = [];
    const label = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        console.log(`imagesSav/cats/${i}.png`)
        await sharp(`imagesSav/cats/${i}.png`)
            .resize(224, 224, {fit: "contain"})
            .toFile(`images/cats/${i}.png`);
        const image = await Jimp.read(`./images/cats/${i}.png`);
        let tensor = tf.tensor(image.bitmap.data).reshape([224,224,-1]);
        console.log(tensor.shape)
        tensor = tensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tensor, [224, 224]).div(tf.scalar(255))
        tensorList.push(tensor);
        label.push(0); // 0 for cat, 1 for dog
    }

    function onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
        console.log('Accuracy', logs.acc);
    }

    const xs = tf.stack(tensorList); //conversion list -> tensor
    const ys = tf.stack(label); //same
    console.log(xs.shape)

    await model.fit(xs,ys,{
        batchSize: 5,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
                // Plot the loss and accuracy values at the end of every training epoch.
                console.log(epoch, logs);
            },
            onTrainStart: console.log("Starting Training..."),
            onTrainEnd: console.log("Training Finished!")
    }}).then(info => {
        console.log('Final accuracy', info.history.acc);
    });
}
```

I know this dataset is too small to gives good results, but I especially want to understand how to launch a model's training on a personal dataset...

There is the results on my shell:

```
imagesSav/cats/0.png
[ 224, 224, 4 ]
imagesSav/cats/1.png
[ 224, 224, 4 ]
imagesSav/cats/2.png
[ 224, 224, 4 ]
imagesSav/cats/3.png
[ 224, 224, 4 ]
imagesSav/cats/4.png
[ 224, 224, 4 ]
[ 5, 224, 224, 4 ]
Starting Training...
Training Finished!
```

I think the problem is due to my tensors formats or because of the NN's architecture, but I'm not sure... Do you have any idea what could be the cause of the problem?